# How do you call the items in ListView?

Tags: android

How do you call the ListView items - objects? or elements? or items? what is the right name for it?

Comment: Either one works.  I tend to use elements.  When talking about their graphical representation, I use rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it whatever you want. I personally call it `items`

When referring to the model, i.e. arrays, I say `objects`.

Answer (score 0):

From [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

> ListView is a view group that displays a list of scrollable **items**. The list **items** are automatically inserted to the list using an Adapter that pulls content from a source such as an array or database query and converts each **item** result into a **view** that's placed into the list.

So, I guess there's no mistake to talk about list items as simply **items** that are converted to **views** when the `Adapter` comes in.